# Does parking a JAVA thread cause any acquired monitors to be released

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock, java.util.concurrent

When thread execution is suspended by parking a thread, does it cause the thread to relinquish ownership of any acquired object monitors?

Put simply, can the following code deadlock if a thread (t1) acquires the monitor for the 'this' object and is parked while another thread (t2) that tries to unpark t1 by first trying to acquire the monitor of 'this' and blocking.

```java
// Thread t1 executes this code first.
syncronized(this) {
    LockSupport.park();
}

// Thread t2 then executes this piece of code.
synchronized(this) {
    LockSupport.unpark(t1);
}
```

Comment: I expect it'll deadlock. Why don't you test it?

Comment: Excellent suggestion - I should have just tested this before asking. Your expectation is right - there is a deadlock.

Comment: It causes a lock. Not a deadlock. A deadlock requires at least two locks.

Comment: There may not be 2 locks but it effective deadlock @EJP.  The more general definition talks about resources not just locks.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be a deadlock because `t1` is blocked and still owns lock on `this` object when `t2` is trying to acquire the same lock.

Answer (score 0):

That would make no sense.

Sometimes a thread needs to hold more than one lock at a time.  Some awful piece of legacy code might do something like this:

```
synchronized(objectA) {
    lockB.lock();
    try {
        doSomethingThatRequiresOwnershipOfBothLocks();
    } finally {
        lockB.unlock();
    }
}
```

It would not solve any problems if the `lockB.lock()` call temporarily *unlocked* the monitor on objectA.